# DirectX 11 on Windows 8 doesn't detect nVidia GeForce GT540M

Tags: drivers, windows-8, nvidia-geforce, directx

I have installed Windows 8 Release Preview, and installed nVidia drivers, but the only graphics card detected by DirectX Diagnostics Tool and DirectX-based games is Intel HD Graphics integrated into my i7 chip. I tried several nVidia drivers versions, using clean installs, as well as updating DirectX, but I had no luck with getting it all working.

The game tested is Eve Online client; it fails to detect nVidia card, even after explicitly setting it to use it in nVidia control panel. The strange part is that League of Legends has no problems with rendering using GeForce; I compared its performance before and after installing drivers and it was definitely improved.

Has anyone encountered and managed to solve this problem, or just knows what to do to make the whole thing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a GT540M but I have seen that all my machines that have Nvidia Graphics tended to have lots of problems on Win8RP, but now that I have updated all of them to release versions the drivers seem to be working normally now.

You may simply just have to update to the release version, then the new Win8 Drivers that they have release can properly take effect.

Comment: Oops, s/developer preview/release preview/ in original post.

Comment: Same solution. I couldn't get my drivers to function normally until i had them running on RTM.

Comment: Damn those academic institutions giving accesses to MSDNAA late... Meh. Still, the funny part is that the drivers seem to work with LoL, but just not with Eve.

Comment: Yeah.i was having the problem where it would be fine in WoW but not on Star Trek Online. Same problems. But when I updated to RTM everything was fine. If this answer is acceptable, please up vote and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many driver problems (just like yours) pre-RTM. Get RTM and most are solved.